# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function in WP only when I am not log in

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

*Only when I am not logged into my WP account*.

I have followed the advice to change the var `$` to `jQuery`, but still getting the same error.

Update:

Sorry I didn't put any code. Well this is the code I would like to work properly. But it doesn't work any jquery from any plugin.

I have Jquery added in my wordpress theme and the galleries were working fine until now.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--customer-logout').html('<a href="https://thepuzzleclub.com.au/puzzle-club-fundraising/">Member Details</a>');
$('.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation').children().append('<li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--customer-logout"><a href="https://thepuzzleclub.com.au/my-account/customer-logout/">Logout</a></li>');
$('#affwp-affiliate-dashboard-tabs').prepend('<li class="affwp-affiliate-dashboard-tab"><a href="https://thepuzzleclub.com.au/my-account/">Account Details</a></li>');
$('#header').append('<a class="icon-member-top" href="https://thepuzzleclub.com.au/my-account/"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="text-log-in">MEMBER AREA</span></a>');
$('#header').append('<a class="icon-join-top" href="https://thepuzzleclub.com.au/become-a-partner/"><i class="fa fa-truck" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="text-log-in">JOIN THE PUZZLE CLUB</span></a>');
$(window).scroll(function() {  
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

     //>=, not <=
    if (scroll >= 60) {
        //clearHeader, not clearheader - caps H
        $("#headerwrap").addClass("fixed-header");
      $("#body").addClass("spacing-top");
        $("#header").addClass("header-on-scroll");
    }
  else{
    $("#headerwrap").removeClass("fixed-header");
    $("#body").removeClass("spacing-top");
    $("#header").removeClass("header-on-scroll");
  }
});
});
</script>
```

Any advice on this ?

Comment: If even jQuery is undefined, you probably doesn't load jQuery if not logged. BUT, we have no idea what is your code nor how do you include jQuery?!

Comment: theme folder header.php file add script <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: check you have load the jQuery probably?? or share you code then others can help you!!!

Comment: _I have followed the advice to change the var `$` to `jQuery`_. what error you getting `$ is not a function` or `jQuery is not a function`

Comment: Wordpress loading jquery default. If jquery dont loading in the frontend, you should first find why it's so. Maybe, some plugin, or theme is deleting jquery from queue. But it's strange. And also, if you got both `$ is not a function` or `jQuery is not a function`, you can be sure, that jquery dont load in the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you load the script in your functions.php

```
    // add it like this
   ///includes/resources/js is the path to your script
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/resources/js/my-script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```